# How to Plot Time-series data on Horizontal bar in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

R::How to Plot Single Horizontal Bar Showing different stages on Continous Time-series Data from startdate to present date and for navigating time a horizontal scrollbar in R?

```
This is my data:
    var_events  time_date   event_duration      veh_id
LD  17-06-2018 13:25    6.52                   B33
WL  17-06-2018 13:25    14.52                  B31
TL  17-06-2018 13:26    0.32                   B32
TE  17-06-2018 13:26    4.58                   B13
UL  17-06-2018 13:26    3.45                   B12
WT  17-06-2018 13:26    5.46                   B25
UL  17-06-2018 13:26    1.56                   B17
TL  17-06-2018 13:26    13.6                   B33
SL  17-06-2018 13:26    0.05                   B32
```

Here is a Example of line chart of Previous code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

df = structure(list(Event_stage = c("SE", "MN", "MN", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "TE", "WL", "TE", "TE", "SE", "TE", "TE", "WL", "WT", "MN", "WL", "TE", "WL", "WL", "WT", "WL", "LD", "WT", "WL", "WT", "WT", "TE", "WL", "LD", "WT", "LD", "MN", "TL", "TE", "WL", "TL", "TL", "WT", "TE", "TE", "LD", "WT", "TL", "LD" ), event_date = structure(c(1529573704, 1529573710, 1529573713, 1529573724, 1529573855, 1529573874, 1529573880, 1529573895, 1529573906, 1529573918, 1529573925, 1529573931, 1529573931, 1529573941, 1529573947, 1529573969, 1529574006, 1529574054, 1529574088, 1529574114, 1529574120, 1529574123, 1529574134, 1529574137, 1529574148, 1529574163, 1529574164, 1529574148, 1529574169, 1529574170, 1529574178, 1529574188, 1529574189, 1529574196, 1529574178, 1529574188, 1529574203, 1529574213, 1529574214, 1529574214, 1529574215, 1529574227, 1529574231, 1529574242, 1529574244, 1529574245, 1529574248, 1529574260, 1529574262), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), stage_duration = c(3.78, 3.47, 2.78, 3.45, 3.32, 4.93, 4.23, 4.22, 3.85, 3.37, 5.88, 5.92, 3.97, 3.7, NA, 4.08, 3.05, 0.57, 11.18, 12.08, 2.6, 3.3, 0.23, 0.85, 0.27, 0.25, 0.82, 10.42, 0.15, 0.43, 1.4, 0.25, 0.7, 0.52, 1.12, 0.45, 12.87, 12.18, 2.92, 0.57, 14.07, 12.72, 17.12, 4.13, 3.13, 0.25, 0.33, 18.98, 1.05), veh_id = c("B35", "B05", "B04", "B08", "B14", "B13", "B04", "B17", "B41", "B05", "B26", "B08", "B35", "B19a", "B10a", "B01a", "B28", "B14", "B14", "B18", "B05", "B37", "B04", "B41", "B04", "B19a", "B04", "B17", "B35", "B13", "B35", "B02b", "B28", "B13", "B19a", "B41", "B02b", "B04", "B15", "B01a", "B41", "B13", "B28", "B27", "B33", "B19a", "B01a", "B19a", "B35")), .Names = c("Event_stage", "event_date", "stage_duration", "veh_id"), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# create ggplot
ggplot(data = df %>% filter(veh_id == "B35"), aes(x = event_date, 
                      y = stage_duration)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Event_stage), size= 3) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/2)+
  labs(x = "Event date", y = "Stage duration")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qxus.png)

This is Sample bar plot, Everything same as in above line chart but instead of line with spikes a Horizontal line or I just want a single bar which is interactive with a Slider/Scrollbar to navigate time ::
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gl51.png)

Something resembling this plot,But only a Single Horizontal bar with a scrollbar from start-time to present-time::
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2urg.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% filter(veh_id == "B35") %>% 
    ggplot(
      aes(
        x = event_date, 
        y = stage_duration)
    ) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    labs(x = "Event date", y = "Stage duration") + 
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @JohnCoene Hi john, I already plotted using geom_bar, What i am  looking for is a Horizontal line with colored points or Single Horizontal bar showing different colors for the duration with a slider/scrollbar below X-axis for navigating time like in the above sample plot i provided.Can you take a look at that....Anyways thanks

Comment: @Nic3500 Hi nic, I already plotted using geom_bar, What i am  looking for is a Horizontal line with colored points or Single Horizontal bar showing different colors for the duration with a slider/scrollbar below X-axis for navigating time like in the above sample plot i provided.Can you take a look at that....Anyways thanks

Comment: @Aleksandr Hey Alex, Posted the Question like you suggested, Please take a look.

Comment: @Z.Lin Hey Lin, Could you take a look at my request?